# Nested JSON to HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file and I'd like to display it:

Item 1 
- Subitem 1.1 
- Subitem 1.2 
... 
Item 2 
... 
etc.

I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){

              $.getJSON("file.json", function(result){


                      $.each(result.items, function(key, val){

                          $("#01").append('<p>' + val.item + '</p>');

                                var id_item;
                                id_item = '0' + key;

                                $.each(val.subitems, function(key, val){
                                    $("#02").append('<p><input type="radio" name =' + id_item + ' id =' + key + '>' + val.content + '</input></p>');
                                  });


                           });
          });
      });

  </script>
  <a href ="index.html">Home</a>

  <div position="relative" id="01">
    <div position="absolute" id="02"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result I get is:

Subitem 1.1 
Subitem 1.2 
... 
etc.

Item 1 
Item 2 
... 
etc.

thank you

Comment: Can you add the content of `file.json` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet shows how you can transform a simple JS object into a HTML representation - does this help?

```js
var items = {
  foo: {
    bar: 1,
    baz: 2,
  },
  foobar: 3
}
$.each(items, function(key, val){
  $("#01").append('<p>' + key + '</p>');
  $.each(val, function(key, val){
    $("#01").append('<p>- ' + key + ':' + val + '</p>');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="01">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, so stupid of me, only one <div> was required for both Items and Subitems, it works now the way I wanted (before I had a <div> for Items and a <div> for Subitems, still very beginner with html, especially with the <div> tag).

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is display print out the data on the page:

```js
var data = [
 {key: [1,2,3]}
];

// Clean output, with 4 indentation spaces
var string = JSON.stringify(data, null, '    ');
$('body').append('<pre>' + string + '</pre>');

// Remove brackets
var noBrackets = string.replace(/[,\[\]:{}]/gi, '');
$('body').append('<pre>' + noBrackets + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```